# Split np.array into subarrays with the same length

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split

I have one-dimensional np.arrays of different lengths. 
What is the most pythonic way to split them into subarrays with the same length n(=384) and leave the last subarray (which is shorter) out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `x` is a 1D array, you can do this:

```
x = x[:384 * (x.shape[0] // 384)].reshape(-1, 384)
```

`x` now has the shape `(n, 384)`. You may access each chunk with `x[i]` where `0 <= i < n`.

Comment: @MihaG. Just a note: If x is a 1D numpy array to begin with, you can speed up the truncation operation with `x.shape[0] // 384`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by "sub-arrays."

If you want a list of size 384 `ndarray` objects, this does exactly as you requested:

```
np.split(x, np.arange(0, x.size, 384))[:-1]
```

You can wrap that in `nd.array()` to get an output equivalent to @COLDSPEED, but probably a bit slower.

The real advantage to this is if you want to join those many `ndarrays` of varying size into one `n x 384` array, concatenation of lists will probably be faster than concatenation of `ndarray` objects